# Karate: XML element changed to have empty namespace

Tags: karate

when a xml message define like below, karate adds empty namespace to child element.

Karate feature

```
Feature: test xml
  Scenario: test xml empty namespace
    * def x =
    """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <validateEmailAddressRequest xmlns="anotherUri">
    <request>
      <email>some@domain.com</email>
    </request>
  </validateEmailAddressRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

    """
    * print x
```

Output

```
16:39:17.009 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <validateEmailAddressRequest xmlns="anotherUri">
         <request xmlns="">
            <email>some@domain.com</email>
         </request>
      </validateEmailAddressRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.4
```

if you look at the `<request>` element in the output it's now has the empty namespace where in feature does not.

That does create a problem when SOAP request hitting the server.

Do you know why this behaviour and how can I override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very interesting and I just tried this and don't see this problem at all. My guess is that the version of the Java runtime you are using may have some bug in the XML libraries. Can you do us a favor and replicate this problem using this process ? https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and make sure you specify the exact OS + Java version.

Meanwhile as a workaround, you can do this - convert the XML to a string, do a Java String.replace() and then re-convert:

```
* xmlstring x = x
* xml x = x.replace(' xmlns=""', '')
* print x
```

EDIT - here is the issue that provides a solution (available in 1.2.0 onwards) https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1587

```
* configure xmlNamespaceAware = true
```

Comment: you're absolutely right. I tried replicating the problem as stated but I couldn't. I tried in the project where I have issue with other dependencies gone and it was ok. So I narrowed down this dependency which is messing it up.

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap-builder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
Will look deeper to see what exactly causing this.
 Thanks a lot Peter.

Comment: @Peter I am using karate 1.2.0 and getting below error when used * configure xmlNamespaceAware = true. unexpected 'configure' key: 'xmlNamespaceAware'. What I am doing wrong? Using this in scenario before sending the request.

Comment: @Maddy because it is not released yet. you can confirm it works by following the developer guide, or you need to wait: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: @Peter I was actually using karate version "1.2.0.RC4" so though it might be released in that one. When are you planning to release version 1.2.0? It will be great if it can be released this month :)

Comment: @PeterThomas As Karate Version 1.2.0 is released and I was testing the above * configure xmlNamespaceAware = true functionality. Even after configuring this xmlns="" is getting added in the response. Is there something else we need to do to make this work?

Comment: @Maddy not that I know of. you know what you should ideally do in that case, all the best