# Karate - Is there a way to keep (or add) DTD in the XML request

Tags: karate

Karate appears to be discarding DTD part of my XML when reading it. My request absolutely has to contain DTD. 
Is there a way for me to add it in without being discarded?

I have tried "set" but obviously it's discarded as well.

I have tried to use "text" but then my referenced values inside XML file are not parsed either, so that doesn't serve the purpose.

`* def req = call read(myXML.xml)`

myXML.xml looks like this

`<!DOCTYPE mytype SYSTEM "RandomDTD.dtd">`

`<mytype>`

`</mytype>`

when i print req what i see is

`<mytype>`

`</mytype>`

Answer (score 0):

Use text and then a string replace before sending the XML. There are plenty of ways, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042773/143475

EDIT: One hint is if you want to make a request using a string, but set the content-type to XML, you can do this:

```
* xmlstring temp = <my>xml</my>
* temp.replace('<my>', '<!DOCTYPE blah><my>')
* header Content-Type = 'application/soap+xml'
* request temp
* method post
```

Comment: text doesn't seem to be friends with read though. It throws me no step-definition error

for now i ended up with string concatenation given that DOCTYPE is the first thing in that xml, appears to be working

Comment: @Maria rename the file to `*.txt` or you can use `karate.readAsString()`

Comment: To not sound like i am rejecting suggestions (which i so happen to have also tried in between asking and replying) I believe I have a particular way of putting together my XML, which prevents me from going through `text` or `readAsString`. Basically i create some data that i then populate in XML and if i change it to `*.txt` or `readAsString` it no longer parses the variables upon `read` (unless i am missing something?)
So for now i resort to combination of xmlstring to read my xml and then create another string with DOCTYPE before my file, which appears to serve my purpose.

Comment: @Maria I don't understand what is so hard. just treat it as a pure string. this will mean that you can't do `set` and all that - so use `String.replace()` instead. you can't have everything. if you still have a problem, follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @Maria and my last suggestion is maybe you should add the DTD as the last step before making the request. so up to that point work in pure XML. does that make sense ?