# KARATE: Should setting an XML body with an updated payload overwrite an existing one with the same name?

Tags: karate

I have created a reusable feature with the goal of taking in a payload as an argument and sending a request containing the received payload.

I have a predefined xml, `envelope`, I use for the request. The problem I'm seeing is when I `set` the payload into the body of the envelope and print out the request, it includes the self-closing tag from the envelope along with the payload I pass in. My intention is to replace the self-closing tag with the tag I am passing in. The self-closing tag is only there for situations in which no argument is supplied, since it is necessary for the request to be valid.

The predefined XML, or `envelope`, looks like this:

```
<ser:getDefaultConfig>
   <DefaultConfigRequest/>
</ser:getDefaultConfig>
```

The reusable looks like this:

```
@Reusable
Feature: Get Default Config

  Background:
    Given url baseUrl + '/DataInterface'
    And xml params = __arg

  Scenario: Get Default Config - getDefaultConfig
    Given set envelope /Envelope/Body = read('classpath:path/to/envelope.xml')
    And set envelope /Envelope/Body/getDefaultConfig = params
    And request envelope
    And header Content-Type = 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
    When method post
    Then def result = response
```

And the calling feature looks like this:

```
Feature: Default Config Integration Test

    Background:
    Given url baseUrl
    And copy envelope = read('classpath:path/to/envelope.xml')
    And copy expectedConfig = defaultConfig


  Scenario: Validate config details optional start and end times
    Given def expectedTimes =
    """
    {
      DefaultConfigRequest:{
        'fromTime': #(fromTime),
        'toTime': #(toTime)
      }
    }
    """

    When def actualFareDetails = call read('classpath:path/to/reusable.feature') expectedTimes
    Then match actualDetails.responseStatus == 200
    And match actualDetails.defaultConfig == expectedDetails
```

The request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://ser">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getDefaultConfig>
         <DefaultConfigRequest/>
         <DefaultConfigRequest>
            <fromTime>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000-07:00</fromTime>
            <toTime>2037-12-31T23:59:00.000-07:00</toTime>
         </DefaultConfigRequest>
      </ser:getDefaultConfig>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but it should not include the self closing `<DefaultConfigRequest/>` tag on the 5th line. I can get rid of it if I remove it from the envelope, but then I have to add some conditional logic to check for a null argument and add it to the request when necessary.

The issue seems to be that it doesn't overwrite the existing tag even when it is set at the same level. Even if I append the tag to the `set` line in the reusable

```
And set envelope /Envelope/Body/getDefaultConfig/DefaultConfigRequest = params
```

karate nests the argument within that tag.

The other thing that is bugging me is I have to wrap both `fromTime` and `toTime` into a parent element `DefaultConfigRequest` in my payload, or else the reusable only sends the first one, `fromTime`.

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this and if this expected behavior? Is there something I'm missing? My coworker and I spent a lot of time experimenting with this and could not come up with a better solution than the one I described above.

Comment: XML is tricky. see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57825429/143475 - if you think it is a bug please follow this process so we can investigate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue