# How to fetch the correlationID value from the xml response, however it is having some different format using karate framework?

Tags: xml, karate

For one SOAP API call we are getting the response like below(sending the dummy response).

```
* def response = 
--uuid:123456
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Header>
  <m:Trans xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/transaction/"
  soap:mustUnderstand="1">234
  </m:Trans>
</soap:Header>
<success>true</success>
<correlationId>123456abcd</correlationId>
...
...
</soap:Envelope>
--uuid:123456--
```

I need to fetch the correlationId(123456abcd) value from the xml response.

I tried the below ways.

1. Replacing the values doesn't work

   - def corrId = response.replace(/.*([^<]+)</correlationId>.*/, '$1')

tried by using so many logics and regular expressions to achieve this, but nothing got worked, can you please help us on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that id in one line like this:

```
* def id = //correlationId
```

Comment: Hi @peterSmith, Thanks for your response. But all this soap response is stored in response variable.


If i tried with the above logic like 
* def id = //correlationId

It is giving the below error.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: @YarasuLavanya refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75626292/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042773/143475